# @EnableTransactionManagement and @Transaction not working with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am making an application using `Maven`, `Spring`, `Hibernate` and `rest APIs`. Following is the hierarchy of my project.
*Persistence* module is complied and is made available for *Business* module and this Business module is made available to *Endpoint* module. Pretty simple.

I am using the `spring annotation` instead of xml and this is the flow that I am trying to implement.

Web based application calls a rest API, in the API there is called a function and in that function a call is made to businessLogic module and in that 
module the persistence module is called in which all the DAOs and its implementation is written. ***Each of these modules has its own Configuration file***. Pretty straigh forward as well.

According to what I have learned, we use the tag `@EnableTransactionManagement` to get the `@Transaction` working.
`@Transaction` tag can be used on function and that function will be considered as a ***single transaction*** no matter how many inserts, updates are called in it.

**Problem:**
Issue is simple, I *don't get any exception* when i start apache or even when i call API that later calls the persistence to save the object.
*No data is inserted the database and no exception is printed in the log file.*

Keeping the hierarchy in mind, following are the files that are used in the project.

> EndpointConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:persistence-hibernate.properties" })
public class EndpointConfiguration{

    @Autowired
    public org.springframework.core.env.Environment environment;


    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.product.persistence" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = "stakeHoldersBusinessLogic")
    public IStakeHoldersBusinessLogic stakeHoldersBusinessLogic(){return new StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl(); }

    @Bean(name = "daoFactoryCustom")
    public DaoFactoryCustom daoFactoryCustom(){return new DaoFactoryCustomHbnImpl(); }

// some more beans

}
```

> StakeHoldersEndpointImplRestController.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9090")
@RequestMapping(value = "/stakeHolders")
@RestController
public class StakeHoldersEndpointImplRestController implements IStakeHoldersEndpoint, InitializingBean {
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/createStakeHolder",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        headers = "Accept="+ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public CreateStakeHolderResponse createStakeHolderEndpoint(@RequestBody CreateStakeHolderRequest request) {
    LOG.trace("StakeHoldersEndpointImplRestController.createStakeHolder () - Start");

    CreateStakeHolderResponse createStakeHolderResponse = new CreateStakeHolderResponse();

    try{
        createStakeHolderResponse = innerFunction(request);
    }catch(Exception exception){
        LOG.error("Exception Occurred : "+exception.getMessage());
    }

    LOG.trace("StakeHoldersEndpointImplRestController.createStakeHolder () - End");
    return createStakeHolderResponse;
}

@Transactional
private CreateStakeHolderResponse innerFunction(CreateStakeHolderRequest request){

    CreateStakeHolderResponse createStakeHolderResponse = new CreateStakeHolderResponse();

    try {
        createStakeHolderResponse = stakeHoldersBusinessLogic.createStakeHolderBusinessLogic(request);
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error("Exception : ",e);
    }
    return createStakeHolderResponse;
}
```

> BusinessLogicConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BusinessLogicConfiguration {

// some beans

}
```

> StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl.java

```
public class StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl implements IStakeHoldersBusinessLogic, InitializingBean {

    public CreateStakeHolderResponse createStakeHolderBusinessLogic(CreateStakeHolderRequest request) {
        LOG.trace("StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl.createStakeHolderBusinessLogic () - Start");

        CreateStakeHolderResponse createStakeHolderResponse = new CreateStakeHolderResponse(
                IConstants.ERROR_CODE_BUSINESS_LOGIC_INITIATED_CODE , IConstants.ERROR_CODE_BUSINESS_LOGIC_INITIATED_STRING);

        try{
            //some logic to convert the request into stakeHolders, which is a Model bean mapped to a table
            daoFactoryCustom.getStakeHoldersDAO().save(stakeHolders, 100L);

        }catch(Exception exception){
            LOG.error("Exception Occurred : ", exception);
        }

        LOG.trace("StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl.createStakeHolderBusinessLogic () - End");
        return createStakeHolderResponse;
    }

}
```

> PersistenceConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfiguration {
// some beans
}
```

> StakeHoldersDAOImpl.java

```
@Autowired(required = true)
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void save(T obj, Long creator) {
    try{
        getSession().save(obj);
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error("Exception : ",e);
    }
}

public final Session getSession() {
    Session session;
    try{
        session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }catch (HibernateException e){
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    return session;
}
```

I have been on it for more then a week and could not find why is this happening.
Log trace to this call is below.

```
18:09:14.653 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : 193 - Read [class com.product.contract.requests.CreateStakeHolderRequest] as "application/json" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@30b367c7]
18:09:14.719 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : 134 - Invoking [StakeHoldersEndpointImplRestController.createStakeHolderEndpoint] method with arguments [com.product.contract.requests.CreateStakeHolderRequest@17b06234]
18:09:14.719 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE com.product.endpoint.controller.impl.StakeHoldersEndpointImplRestController : 47 - StakeHoldersEndpointImplRestController.createStakeHolder () - Start
18:09:14.720 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE com.product.businesslogic.impl.StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl : 100 - StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl.createStakeHolderBusinessLogic () - Start
18:09:14.743 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl : 1201 - Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null, owner=null
18:09:14.912 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl : 229 - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
18:09:14.921 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator : 82 - Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
18:09:14.934 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl : 281 - Opened Session [e4202ec0-7fd9-4333-9db4-efefa24d7c53] at timestamp: 14952857548
18:09:14.938 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener : 163 - Saving transient instance
18:09:14.949 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL : 92 - 
    select
        nextval ('pro5.entity_large')
18:09:14.950 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource : 142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres]
18:09:14.980 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 55 - Registering statement [select nextval ('pro5.entity_large')]
18:09:15.086 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 182 - Registering result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@1d32dd3f]
18:09:15.092 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure : 101 - Sequence value obtained: 500046
18:09:15.093 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 91 - Releasing result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@1d32dd3f]
18:09:15.093 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 132 - Closing result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@1d32dd3f]
18:09:15.093 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 68 - Releasing statement [select nextval ('pro5.entity_large')]
18:09:15.093 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 73 - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
18:09:15.093 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 148 - Closing prepared statement [select nextval ('pro5.entity_large')]
18:09:15.094 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl : 263 - Starting afterQuery statement execution processing [AFTER_TRANSACTION]
18:09:15.095 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener : 118 - Generated identifier: 500046, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
18:09:15.096 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener : 157 - Saving [com.product.persistence.model.StakeHolders#500046]
18:09:15.116 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue : 244 - Adding an EntityInsertAction for [com.product.persistence.model.StakeHolders] object
18:09:15.120 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue : 98 - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
18:09:15.121 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister : 1338 - Getting current persistent state for: [com.product.persistence.model.keyValuePair.CancellationReason#0]
18:09:15.122 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL : 92 - 
    select
        cancellati_.id_cancellation,
        cancellati_.dat_last_update as dat_last4_1_,
        cancellati_.id_customer_last_update as id_custo5_1_,
        cancellati_.str_cancellation_reason as str_canc6_1_ 
    from
        pro5.cancellation_reason cancellati_ 
    where
        cancellati_.id_cancellation=?
18:09:15.123 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 55 - Registering statement [select cancellati_.id_cancellation, cancellati_.dat_last_update as dat_last4_1_, cancellati_.id_customer_last_update as id_custo5_1_, cancellati_.str_cancellation_reason as str_canc6_1_ from pro5.cancellation_reason cancellati_ where cancellati_.id_cancellation=?]
18:09:15.127 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : 65 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
18:09:15.168 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 182 - Registering result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@1f3e3b2c]
18:09:15.171 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor : 51 - extracted value ([dat_last4_1_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [null]
18:09:15.172 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor : 51 - extracted value ([id_custo5_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [null]
18:09:15.174 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor : 61 - extracted value ([str_canc6_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Fraud]
18:09:15.175 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 91 - Releasing result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@1f3e3b2c]
18:09:15.175 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 132 - Closing result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@1f3e3b2c]
18:09:15.175 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 68 - Releasing statement [select cancellati_.id_cancellation, cancellati_.dat_last_update as dat_last4_1_, cancellati_.id_customer_last_update as id_custo5_1_, cancellati_.str_cancellation_reason as str_canc6_1_ from pro5.cancellation_reason cancellati_ where cancellati_.id_cancellation=0]
18:09:15.176 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 73 - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
18:09:15.176 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 148 - Closing prepared statement [select cancellati_.id_cancellation, cancellati_.dat_last_update as dat_last4_1_, cancellati_.id_customer_last_update as id_custo5_1_, cancellati_.str_cancellation_reason as str_canc6_1_ from pro5.cancellation_reason cancellati_ where cancellati_.id_cancellation=0]
18:09:15.176 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl : 263 - Starting afterQuery statement execution processing [AFTER_TRANSACTION]
18:09:15.177 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue : 98 - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
18:09:15.177 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister : 1338 - Getting current persistent state for: [com.product.persistence.model.keyValuePair.Cities#0]
18:09:15.178 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL : 92 - 
    select
        cities_.id_city,
        cities_.dat_last_update as dat_last4_2_,
        cities_.id_customer_last_update as id_custo5_2_,
        cities_.str_city as str_city6_2_ 
    from
        pro5.cities cities_ 
    where
        cities_.id_city=?
18:09:15.178 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 55 - Registering statement [select cities_.id_city, cities_.dat_last_update as dat_last4_2_, cities_.id_customer_last_update as id_custo5_2_, cities_.str_city as str_city6_2_ from pro5.cities cities_ where cities_.id_city=?]
18:09:15.179 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : 65 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]
18:09:15.199 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 182 - Registering result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@7b2493e9]
18:09:15.200 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor : 51 - extracted value ([dat_last4_2_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [null]
18:09:15.200 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor : 51 - extracted value ([id_custo5_2_] : [BIGINT]) - [null]
18:09:15.201 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor : 61 - extracted value ([str_city6_2_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Lahore]
18:09:15.201 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 91 - Releasing result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@7b2493e9]
18:09:15.201 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 132 - Closing result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@7b2493e9]
18:09:15.202 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 68 - Releasing statement [select cities_.id_city, cities_.dat_last_update as dat_last4_2_, cities_.id_customer_last_update as id_custo5_2_, cities_.str_city as str_city6_2_ from pro5.cities cities_ where cities_.id_city=0]
18:09:15.202 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 73 - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
18:09:15.202 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 148 - Closing prepared statement [select cities_.id_city, cities_.dat_last_update as dat_last4_2_, cities_.id_customer_last_update as id_custo5_2_, cities_.str_city as str_city6_2_ from pro5.cities cities_ where cities_.id_city=0]
18:09:15.202 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl : 263 - Starting afterQuery statement execution processing [AFTER_TRANSACTION]
18:09:15.203 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue : 98 - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
18:09:15.203 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister : 1338 - Getting current persistent state for: [com.product.persistence.model.StakeHoldersType#10]
18:09:15.203 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL : 92 - 
    select
        stakeholde_.id_stake_holder_type,
        stakeholde_.id_str_role as id_str_r3_25_,
        stakeholde_.str_stake_holder_desc as str_stak2_25_ 
    from
        pro5.stake_holders_type stakeholde_ 
    where
        stakeholde_.id_stake_holder_type=?
18:09:15.204 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 55 - Registering statement [select stakeholde_.id_stake_holder_type, stakeholde_.id_str_role as id_str_r3_25_, stakeholde_.str_stake_holder_desc as str_stak2_25_ from pro5.stake_holders_type stakeholde_ where stakeholde_.id_stake_holder_type=?]
18:09:15.205 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : 65 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [10]
18:09:15.208 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 182 - Registering result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@3c215e9d]
18:09:15.209 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor : 51 - extracted value ([id_str_r3_25_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null]
18:09:15.210 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor : 61 - extracted value ([str_stak2_25_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Transport]
18:09:15.210 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 91 - Releasing result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@3c215e9d]
18:09:15.210 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 132 - Closing result set [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@3c215e9d]
18:09:15.211 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 68 - Releasing statement [select stakeholde_.id_stake_holder_type, stakeholde_.id_str_role as id_str_r3_25_, stakeholde_.str_stake_holder_desc as str_stak2_25_ from pro5.stake_holders_type stakeholde_ where stakeholde_.id_stake_holder_type=10]
18:09:15.212 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 73 - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
18:09:15.212 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl : 148 - Closing prepared statement [select stakeholde_.id_stake_holder_type, stakeholde_.id_str_role as id_str_r3_25_, stakeholde_.str_stake_holder_desc as str_stak2_25_ from pro5.stake_holders_type stakeholde_ where stakeholde_.id_stake_holder_type=10]
18:09:15.212 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl : 263 - Starting afterQuery statement execution processing [AFTER_TRANSACTION]
18:09:15.213 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue : 257 - Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityInsertAction[com.product.persistence.model.StakeHolders#500046]]
18:09:15.213 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue : 280 - Adding resolved non-early insert action.
18:09:15.216 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue : 98 - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
18:09:15.216 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue : 98 - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
18:09:15.216 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue : 98 - ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
18:09:15.225 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE com.product.businesslogic.impl.StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl : 152 - StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl.createStakeHolderBusinessLogic () - End
18:09:15.225 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE com.product.endpoint.controller.impl.StakeHoldersEndpointImplRestController : 82 - StakeHoldersEndpointImplRestController.createStakeHolder () - End
18:09:15.226 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : 138 - Method [createStakeHolderEndpoint] returned [com.product.contract.responses.CreateStakeHolderResponse@6aac8e42]
18:09:15.301 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : 226 - Written [com.product.contract.responses.CreateStakeHolderResponse@6aac8e42] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@30b367c7]
18:09:15.302 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : 1036 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
18:09:15.302 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : 1059 - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@70e62c16
18:09:15.302 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : 997 - Successfully completed request
18:09:15.302 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext : 363 - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/endpoint/stakeHolders/createStakeHolder]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[807ms]; status=[OK]
18:09:15.302 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext : 363 - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/endpoint/stakeHolders/createStakeHolder]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[807ms]; status=[OK]
```

What am I doing wrong in all this, any help would be great.

Thank you

Irshad Ahmad.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `@Transactional` does not work on private methods in Proxy mode (which is the default).

Second, it's a bit unusual to annotate controller methods with `@Transactional`. Usually you annotate service class with it (or DAO class if you only have DAO and no service).

So I would suggest the following:

1. Annotate `StakeHoldersBusinessLogicImpl` with `@Transactional` (as this seems to be your service)
2. Remove `@Transactional` from your controller method

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking out time and look into such a long post and understand whats happening. As per the the 2 suggestions,  tried both but neither worked but will upvote cause that should work, there must be some issue with my configuration or something else.

Comment: Could you please update the post with the new code and log?

Comment: Firstly extremely sorry for not responding, was away on leaves. Secondly there were few issues with the configuration and code. Spring and Hibernate versions that i was using were not compatible. Another thing, when i was using @Transnational on both Endpoint and Business Logic, it was also causing problem. I am using this annotation on only function that is in the Endpoint with private access modifier and it is working. Thank you again for follow up,